# Bootstrap tooltip - show ok in mobile Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, mobile-safari, responsiveness

I am currently struggling with something I suspect is Bootstrap or Safari bug. When I use Bootstrap tooltips on my page, they work great both on desktop and mobile with one exception - mobile Safari. They seem not to show at all.

I don't know whether it is Safari or Bootstrap bug but I'm looking for some solution. Can somebody help me? I would like some CSS or JS *hack* the most since it would not be necessary to change anything. But some other tooltip library would also be fine - the best would be if I wouldn't have to change my HTML code, so I would initialize the tooltips like

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"
```

Thanks for all of your answers!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is 4 years late but you need to add "click" to the trigger option to make the tool tip work on safari iPhone.

Comment: This does not seem enough, though. You also need to add `role="button"` to the element. The tooltip will now appear... but never disappear. I will be looking into this and update if I find a workaround.